# Angular models and interfaces organization

Tags: angular, typescript

Angular styleguide has information about best practices of using classes and interfaces in application. But it has't any information about how can I organize my interfaces and model classes.

There is a question: is there any best practices about file and class organization?

- Should I store all domain classes and interfaces in one file or create separate file for each interface?
- Should I hold model classes and interfaces in different files or in one?
- If component or service has some infrastrucutre classes and interfaces what about it organization (one or more files, suffixes, etc.)?
- Which suffixes for model files are most common in angular world?

For example, what is the better way of following?

user-service.model.ts

```
export enum Gender {MALE, FEMALE}

export interface UserStatus {
  id: string;
  caption: string;
}

export interface User {
  name: string;
  gender: Gender;
  status: UserStatus;
}

export interface UserListResponse extends ListResponse<User> {}
```

or

user-gender.model.ts

```
export enum Gender {MALE, FEMALE}
```

user-status.model.ts

```
export interface UserStatus {
  id: string;
  caption: string;
}
```

user.model.ts

```
export interface User {
  name: string;
  gender: Gender;
  status: UserStatus;
}
```

user-list-response.model.ts

```
export interface UserListResponse extends ListResponse<User> {}
```

UPD:
I understand that it can be descided by each team internally and depends on internal agreements, but I interested in "How another developers do this?"

Comment: This likely depends on your own way to develop, we usually do a deep separation between models, interfaces and components, whereas components and relative services are wrapped in the same folder, while classes and interfaces those depends on are isolated to a separate folder. In general, keep in mind that the more people work on the same project, the more likely you will need to split the files, so that version control won't be painful, since having many people working on the same file can lead to undesired conflicts.In a nutshell, this is kind of personal anyway, mine are just considerations.

Comment: Sounds good, but it seems to me that create "two-lines" file for each "specific" component interface like "ListOption" with value and name fields and "ListSelection" with array of ListOptions is not good idea..

Comment: This largely depends, once again, on how big your project is. That interface / component / whatever may become bigger in the next year or so, so it's really matter of how you feel your code should be organized. Just keep in mind that it should be readable and easy to consult / edit and **mantain**, that's important.

Answer (score 1):

This is could depends on you.

I prefer keep all model in it's own file, grouping specifc model in the same file like `UserStatus`, `User` and `UserListResponse`.

But the `Gender` enum could be used on other model/interfaces like `Customer` and should be on a separated file.

**PS**: The `one file per class/interface` approach will help you know or infer on which file name is an specific class/interface when you need to edit it.

Comment: Grouping models by "domains" not by related service or component is good idea, thanks. Do you keep model files byside with related component or service or create separate folders somewhere?

Comment: I use a dedicated folder to keep all my models, like `./src/models/` or `./src/shared/models`. The idea is somewhere where all the components and services could access using the simplest path